# QSignalMapper vs. grabbing senderId Performance

Tags: c++, qt, optimization

For mapping multiple custom signals in one slot in qt i basically have two options: the QSignalMapper or the cast from the senderID pointer (see: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq10-signalmapper.html).

My question is: which is more efficient code?
I want to use it in a timecritical section of my program.

Should i consider using seperate Signals/Slots to optimzie the code?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're most likely wrong about what "time critical" means and where is your application actually spending the CPU time. You can't make any arguments without actually measuring things. At this point I believe you're micro-optimizing and wasting your time. Don't do anything optimization-related unless you can measure the starting point and see any improvements in real numbers.

If your signal-slot connection is invoked on the order of 1000 times per second, you can do pretty much anything you want - the overhead won't matter. It only starts to matter if you're in the 100k invocations/second range, and then probably you're architecting things wrongly to begin with.

A signal-slot connection without any parameters is always faster than one that sends some parameters. You can simply add a property to the sender object using the dynamic property system, and check for that property by using `sender()->property("...")`. Dynamic property look-up takes a bit more time than using `qobject_cast<...>(sender())` and a call to a member function on a custom `QObject` or `QWidget`-derived class. But this is immaterial, because unless you can measure the difference, you don't need to worry about it. Premature optimization is truly the root of all evil.

Comment: You are correct: My answer to most of this kinds of questions is also: "don't optimize unless you really have a problem and definitly know that this the cause". However, I was just wondering if there is an easy answer which lies in the implementation of the signal mapper or the senderId which is very expensive (using RTTI and look up tables or something like that) which should be avoided in often called (>1000 per scond) code. But thank you fore the hint with the property which i could test if there is a problem. Until then I'll stay with the qsignalmapper and qobject_cast which seems to work.